# Counterexamples to "If $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0$, then for large enough $x$,$f(x)$ gets closer and closer to $0$, without ever equalling $0$."

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm working through a test question, in which I'm given the following statement:

> If $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$, then for large enough $x$,$f(x)$ gets
>   closer and closer to $0$, without ever equalling $0$.

To that, I'm given some options and have to decide which is correct. The options of interest are as follows:

a) The statement is false, and $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ is a counterexample.

b) The statement is false, and $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ is a counterexample.

Clearly $\displaystyle \frac{\sin x}{x}=0$ every $\pi n$ radians ($n$ any integer), so this is an answer. Indeed, this is the correct answer to the question.

However, I propose $\displaystyle f(1)=\frac{\ln(1)}{1}=0$. Why isn't this a counterexample to the original statement?

Comment: Note the detail "for large enough $x$" you wrote: $1$ is not a sequence diverging to $\infty$, while $n \pi$ is.

Comment: To be fair to OP, I think the wording on this question is _terrible_.  It's not at all clear that 'without ever equalling zero' is a subclause of 'for large enough $x$' and not an independent statement. If I had any say over the test I would seek to have that question replaced.

Comment: I guess that they only talk about values of $x$ greater than $1$.... You should check what's the domain of $f$.